# Custom Permission - Error in Winter '15 Release Notes?

Tags: permissions, release, winter15

In WI15 release notes (Force.com customization section, pag.178),  it's explained how Custom Permissions work, and particularly it's said that a custom permisssion could be set as required for another one. 
Now, the release note PDF says, exactly :

• You can specify required custom permissions for other custom permissions. A required custom permission is a custom permission that must be enabled when the **PARENT** custom permission is enabled.

I'm wondering if there's some error in saying PARENT instead of CHILD. I want to say : a required permission can be parent, not the "requiring" one. So, if a custom permission requires another permission to be enabled , the PARENT permission seems to be the one that is Required!

Where is my theory wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a typo.